# How to take multiple values from a python list?

Tags: python

I am creating a program that takes user input stores it in a list and then multiplies by either 5 or 1 alternating between each number. eg the first value is multiplied by 5 and the next 1 and so on. I want to remove all the values that i would multiply by 5 and add them to a separate list. How would this be done?

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=List1[???]
```

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: I have tried writing it like this:

List2=List1[0,1]

list2=List1[0][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2 = [i*5 for i in list1[1::2]]
```

Two methods are used here [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) and [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

Comment: Maybe explaining what you are doing to help OP understand, rather than just giving the answer?

Comment: @MooingRawr You have a point. Hope OP finds these links useful.

Answer (score 0):

To get every other element, you could use a slice with a stride of two:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list2 = list1[::2]
>>> list2
[1, 3]
```

You can use a similar technique to get the remaining elements:

```
>>> list3 = list1[1::2]
>>> list3
[2, 4]
```

For further information, see [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: This method doesn't remove the items from list1 that would be multiplied by 5 as OP mentioned.